# How do i copy the whole row if the value in a particular column is as required?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need some help here...
What I want to do is copy all the rows from a sheet which have a value 'open POs' in column R in other words every row that has a value 'open POs' in column R should be copied to another google sheet.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Source sheet is the current sheet
  var srcSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Open destination sheet using spreadsheet ID found in url
  // See reference below on how top locate spreadsheet id
  var dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('destination sheet ID');

  // Get values of source sheet
  var srcData = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  srcData.forEach(function(row){
    // If column R is 'open POs'
    if(row[17] == 'open POs') {
      // Add to last row of dstSheet
      dstSheet.appendRow(row)
    }
  });
  // Send destination sheet link to email with subject
  MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", "subject", dstSheet.getUrl());
}
```

#### Data Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Columns hidden for column R visibility

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id)

Comment: Can u please tell me this...
I need to run the code every day in the morning so i would want the code to clear the filled data first then paste the new data... How to do that??

Comment: In other words, you want to move the data instead of just copying it? Copying then after that, deleting the data in the source? @OvaisMajid

Comment: I figured that out now...I added dstSheet.getRange('A2:J100').clearContent(); in the code.. Thank you so much...I know this would sound lame now but how do i email this spreadsheet ???Please help...

Comment: Hi @OvaisMajid, if you want to send the sheet where you only have 'open POs', then just add this on the last line of your function. `MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", "subject", dstSheet.getUrl());`. What this does is send the URL or link of the destination sheet where you sent your 'open POs' data. Modify the email and subject right before running the function.

Comment: I got this  
TypeError: dstSheet.getUrl is not a function
copyOpenTasks @ FilterEmp2.gs:19

Comment: Can you add your code on the post? `dstSheet` should be a spreadsheet class

Comment: I updated my answer @OvaisMajid, it should still be inside your function and at the same time, at the last line.

Comment: Dear @NaziA, I cannot thank you enough for your help, please help me with one more thing, the dstSheet is a tab in a googlesheet which contains many such tabs... what i want to do is email this particular tab not the whole sheet in excel format not in pdf format...I want to send the sheet as an attachment not send it as a link... Please help

Comment: Hi @OvaisMajid, Thank you for replying. I'm glad your original issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is completely different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it.